# How can I make preview of NEFs happen inside Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, codec, camera-raw

Nikon does publish a "NEF Codec", which supposedly makes image programs able to recognize and use NEF files. However, it does not seem to cause Explorer to recognize the files:

[image: Explorer with NEF files]

Is this possible?

Comment: What Nikon progam have you installed? Have you tried to set the file associate in Control Panel>Programs>Default Programs>Associate a file type or protocol with a program? Does the NEF file type even show in there?

Comment: @KCotreau: Just the codec mentioned in the question: http://nikonimglib.com/nefcodec/ -- There's no way to associate it with a file type because it's just a codec, not a viewer.

Comment: Are you running 64-bit Windows?  AFAIK, the WIC codec is 32-bit only. The [FastPictureViewer Codec Pack](http://www.fastpictureviewer.com/codecs/) should work for you, though it's not free.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to adding RAW file support in Windows Photo Viewer, Microsoft's [Camera Codec Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26829) also enables Explorer to create thumbnails of NEF files.

Answer (score -1):

Fromt the questions above:

> "Have you tried to set the file
>   associate in Control
>   Panel>Programs>Default
>   Programs>Associate a file type or
>   protocol with a program? Does the NEF
>   file type even show in there?"
>
> @KCotreau: Just the codec mentioned in
>   the question: nikonimglib.com/nefcodec
>   -- There's no way to associate it with a file type because it's just a codec,
>   not a viewer.

That is your answer then. File associations, like what you are trying to do in that explorer window screenshot, are associated with programs that open them. You need a program that can open them, and can probably get one here:

http://support.nikonusa.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/61/~/current-versions-of-nikon-software

Comment: It works just fine with JPEGs, and I don't have a program associated with those.

Comment: by default, i think windows viewer is associated with them

Comment: @ Billy ONeal I have NEVER seen a computer that did not have a program associated with JPEG, whether Window Viewer as JG said, or IE, or Firefox, etc.